# For loop results line by line printing in template using django view

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-views, django-templates

Hi I am newbie to django and I am trying to print the for loop results in a template using django view but I am not able to print all the lines

My view:

```
def upload(request):
   cells= [(1,2,3,4),(3,3,4,5)]
   i = 0
   for cell in cells:
      a,b,c.d = cell[0],cell[1],cell[2],cell[3]
      I=[b+d,a+c]
      i=i+1
      print(I)
   return render(request,'res.html',{"text":I})
```

res.html:

```
{% for i in text %}
    <div class="row">
        {{ i }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}





when I tried only for loop in python IDE my output is 
    [6, 4]
    [8, 7]
but when I tried in django view I am getting only first row
[6, 4]   and also not able to print this in res.html
```

Please help me out from this thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "text" inside the context that you're passing to the template will be whatever I is on the last loop iteration. Perhaps you want to declare a list before the loop and then append I to it on very iteration. By the way you should really think about your naming conventions and use capitals only for class names and not for variables.

Edit:

Maybe it can look like this:

```
def upload(request):
   cells= [(1,2,3,4),(3,3,4,5)]
   i = 0
   final_results = []
   for cell in cells:
      a,b,c,d = cell[0],cell[1],cell[2],cell[3]
      I=[b+d,a+c]
      i=i+1
      print(I)
      final_results.append(I)
   return render(request,'res.html',{"final_results":final_results})
```

Then inside the template you can loop over it:

```
{% for result in final_results %}
    <div class="row">
        {{ result }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

That will print I inside {{result}} for every loop iteration. I know you may be experimenting but it'd be good if you had a more concrete example of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @somecallibtules can you show with an example if you dont mind please

Comment: even in the cmd after running I am getting only first row i.e print(I) how can I get this please help me @somecallitblues

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
def upload(request):
    I = []
    i = 0
    cells = [(1, 2, 3, 4), (3, 3, 4, 5)]
    for cell in cells:
        a, b, c, d = cell[0], cell[1], cell[2], cell[3]
        I.append([b+d, a+c])
        print(I)
        i += 1
        return render(request, 'res.html', {"text": I})
```

Comment: still I am getting [6,4] in my html page not getting two rows

Comment: in your html page print(len(text)). I'm waiting for your answer. @coder

Comment: Yes thank you the above answer worked for me Soroosh thank you for your time

Comment: I will appreciate you, if you mark my answer as the answer. Good luck. @coder